# Eclipse support for xml files

Tags: xml, eclipse

Does eclipse have capabilities like IntelliJ Idea for xml files? For example, in IntelliJ i can see all the targets through a short cut etc.

Comment: You have ant view in eclipse to go through all the target in the ant xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. While you have your xml file open, make sure the *Outline* view is open (if not: `Window` > `Show View` > `Outline`) where you can inspect the xml content.